# Can't Find this view for fragment transaction?

Tags: android, android-fragments

This is my `ItemListFragment`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/dark_gray"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".15"
        android:weightSum="10"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:layout_height="0dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/action_back"
            android:id="@+id/imageView2" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="6"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:weightSum="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <Spinner
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/idSpinner"
                style="@style/TextViewSpinnerItem"
                android:popupBackground="@color/dark_gray"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight=".8"
                android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".2"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:src="@drawable/down"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView

            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:text="sort"
            android:layout_weight="1.5"
            android:background="@drawable/iconssort"
            android:id="@+id/btnSort" />

        <ImageView

            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:background="@drawable/iconsfilter"
            android:layout_weight="1.5"
            android:id="@+id/btnFilter" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".85"
        android:id="@+id/mapContainer"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/lvCategoryItems"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I want replace a **map fragment** in the container like a `FrameLayout` having id `mapContainer`. But my above layout is already resided inside a **fragment not in activity** at runtime..

```
Fragment fragment = new MapViewFragment();
FragmentManager manager =   getActivity.getSupportFragmentManager();
manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.mapContainer,   fragment).commit();
```

When I am trying to do fragment transaction in this container.

It is giving : no view found having id `"@+id/Mapcontainer"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you call the code replace fragment after onCreateView of ItemListFragment? Because the view mapContainer only exist after ItemListFragment attached to layout. 
And because you add a fragment inside another fragment, I think you should use `FragmentManager manager =   getChildFragmentManager();`

Answer (score 0):

Your fragment class initialization is wrong...

Change the code

```
Fragment fragment = new MapViewFragment();
FragmentManager manager =   getActivity.getSupportFragmentManager();
manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.mapContainer,   fragment).commit();
```

to

```
MapViewFragment fragment = new MapViewFragment();
FragmentManager manager =   getActivity.getSupportFragmentManager();
manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.mapContainer,   fragment).commit();
```

And make sure that the id of your container, ie, the framelayout(probably) is correct... R.id.mapContainer should be the id of the framelayout in the MainActivity...